# Propensity Scores Weighted DID

Tags: econometrics, matching, propensity-scores, difference-in-difference

I have a tough challenge using the DID. I have only 2 year data set, 2010 and 2015. The first is the baseline and the latter is follow-up year. In order to obtain true causal effect using DID, I should ensure that common trend assumption is satisfied in the pre period (though the post is what I really need), which is in my case is impossible due to data limitation. Another case is that the covariates between treated units and the controlled units are very likely unbalanced. Basically I compare apples with oranges.

This condition makes me to use what I called as propensity score-weighted DID. So, I run a probit regression first to obtain propensity scores for each units using baseline data. I use the propensity score as weight to each sample in implementing the DID which is a panel data set-based. The weight for treated units is 1 and for the controlled units is p/(1-p) where p is propensity scores of each controlled units. Then I will get DID estimator.

Did I do the right procedures?

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, both the propensity score matching DID (PSM DID) and the inverse probability weighting (IPW DID) that you want to do are sensible ways to approach this: matching and weighting will take care of the selection into treatment based on observables, and the DID will deal with selection on unobservables as long as the bias from it is time-invariant, conditional on covariates. Matching is just an attempt to approximate what weighting is doing directly. If you're just worried about covariate imbalance, you can include them as controls, as long as they are variables that affect *both* treatment and the outcome, and are not affected by the treatment itself or by anticipation of treatment.

Also, as an aside, you can never test the parallel paths or trends/growth assumptions, even if you had more data. All you can say is that is seems to hold in the pre-treatment period, so you would be more willing to believe it holds in the post-treatment future. But is is still an assumption.

In the example below, your IPW approach will produce estimates that match what Stata's own `teffects ipw` would give you for the ATET/ATT and ATE. I will also demonstrate some alternative matching methods that you might find useful as a robustness check. Why? With IPW, things can go south if the estimated propensity scores are near zero or 1 since you would be dividing by small numbers. This is not the case in this example, and so the estimates are fairly similar. Asymptotically, both PSM and IPW should give you the same answer (though I cannot recall where I saw this result).

Below I will employ a user-written command that can do two-period Kernel PSM DID called `diff`. I will also do a regression version with the kernel-based weights from the command. Finally, you can also trick matching estimators, like user-written `psmatch2` or Stata's own `teffects ipw`, to do DID with two periods, or you can also do a regression version of ipw.

Here's the annotated example:

```
. set more off

. estimates clear

. use http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/c/CardKrueger1994.dta, clear
(Dataset from Card&Krueger (1994))

. /* Need to balance the panels so that all the methods use the same sample */
. drop if missing(fte)
(19 observations deleted)

. bys id (t): keep if _N==2
(23 observations deleted)

. 
. /* (1) -diff- to get ATT */
. diff fte, treated(treated) period(t) id(id) cov(bk kfc roys) kernel ktype(gaussian) support bw(0.05) cluster(id) robust // report
KERNEL PROPENSITY SCORE MATCHING DIFFERENCE-IN-DIFFERENCES
    Estimation on common support
    Matching iterations...
..............................................................................................................................................................................
> ............................................................................................................................................
DIFFERENCE-IN-DIFFERENCES ESTIMATION RESULTS
Number of observations in the DIFF-IN-DIFF: 778
            Baseline       Follow-up
   Control: 75             75          150
   Treated: 314            314         628
            389            389
------------------------------------------------------
 Outcome var.   | fte     | S. Err. |   t   |  P>|t|
----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------
Baseline        |         |         |       | 
   Control      | 20.471  |         |       | 
   Treated      | 17.069  |         |       | 
   Diff (T-C)   | -3.402  | 1.481   | -2.30 | 0.022**
Follow-up       |         |         |       | 
   Control      | 17.792  |         |       | 
   Treated      | 17.518  |         |       | 
   Diff (T-C)   | -0.274  | 1.067   | -0.26 | 0.798
                |         |         |       | 
Diff-in-Diff    | 3.128   | 1.388   | 2.25  | 0.025**
------------------------------------------------------
R-square:    0.02
* Means and Standard Errors are estimated by linear regression
**Robust Std. Errors
**Clustered Std. Errors
**Inference: *** p<0.01; ** p<0.05; * p<0.1

. assert _support==1

. 
. /* (2a) Regression Using Kernel Weights for ATE */
. reg fte i.treated##i.t [aw=_weights], cluster(id) robust
(sum of wgt is   1.2560e+03)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        778
                                                F(3, 388)         =       2.04
                                                Prob > F          =     0.1075
                                                R-squared         =     0.0193
                                                Root MSE          =        9.5

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |  -3.401828   1.481415    -2.30   0.022    -6.314433   -.4892233
         1.t |  -2.679224   1.307741    -2.05   0.041    -5.250369   -.1080794
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   3.128269   1.388281     2.25   0.025     .3987744    5.857763
             |
       _cons |    20.4711    1.39505    14.67   0.000     17.72829     23.2139
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtset id t
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  t, 0 to 1
                delta:  1 unit

. xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [aw=_weights], fe cluster(id) robust
note: 1.treated omitted because of collinearity

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =        778
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        389

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0376                                         min =          2
     between = 0.0065                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.0000                                         max =          2

                                                F(2,388)          =       2.57
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.1104                        Prob > F          =     0.0781

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |          0  (omitted)
         1.t |  -2.679224   1.306897    -2.05   0.041     -5.24871   -.1097388
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   3.128269   1.387385     2.25   0.025     .4005359    5.856002
             |
       _cons |   18.77018   .3468462    54.12   0.000     18.08825    19.45211
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  8.0179596
     sigma_e |  6.8873514
         rho |  .57541878   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* Create ATT and ATE Weights for regressions*/
. /* You can install -xfill- by typing net from https://www.sealedenvelope.com/ and clicking on the name */
. xfill _ps, i(id)

. gen double w_att = cond(treated==1,1,_ps/(1-_ps))

. gen double w_ate = cond(treated==1,1/_ps,1/(1-_ps))

. 
. /* (2b) Regression Using ATT and ATE IPW Weights */
. reg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_att] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
(sum of wgt is   1.2560e+03)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        778
                                                F(3, 388)         =       1.48
                                                Prob > F          =     0.2187
                                                R-squared         =     0.0079
                                                Root MSE          =     9.4359

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |  -1.897508   1.458586    -1.30   0.194    -4.765229    .9702128
         1.t |  -2.182001   1.170245    -1.86   0.063    -4.482815     .118813
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   2.631046   1.259607     2.09   0.037     .1545361    5.107555
             |
       _cons |   18.96678   1.370783    13.84   0.000     16.27168    21.66187
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. reg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_ate] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
(sum of wgt is   1.5560e+03)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        778
                                                F(3, 388)         =       1.53
                                                Prob > F          =     0.2068
                                                R-squared         =     0.0086
                                                Root MSE          =     9.4409

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |  -2.014025   1.455524    -1.38   0.167    -4.875727    .8476772
         1.t |  -2.247811   1.184075    -1.90   0.058    -4.575816    .0801949
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   2.712311   1.275497     2.13   0.034     .2045602    5.220061
             |
       _cons |    19.1994   1.367706    14.04   0.000     16.51036    21.88845
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_att], fe cluster(id) robust
note: 1.treated omitted because of collinearity

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =        778
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        389

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0275                                         min =          2
     between = 0.0065                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.0000                                         max =          2

                                                F(2,388)          =       2.21
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.1023                        Prob > F          =     0.1116

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |          0  (omitted)
         1.t |  -2.182001   1.169489    -1.87   0.063    -4.481331    .1173282
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   2.631046   1.258794     2.09   0.037     .1561344    5.105957
             |
       _cons |   18.01802   .3146986    57.25   0.000     17.39929    18.63675
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  8.0031528
     sigma_e |  6.6447787
         rho |  .59194417   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_ate], fe cluster(id) robust
note: 1.treated omitted because of collinearity

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =        778
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        389

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0287                                         min =          2
     between = 0.0065                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.0000                                         max =          2

                                                F(2,388)          =       2.28
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.1037                        Prob > F          =     0.1032

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |          0  (omitted)
         1.t |  -2.247811   1.183311    -1.90   0.058    -4.574314    .0786925
             |
   treated#t |
       NJ#1  |   2.712311   1.274674     2.13   0.034     .2061786    5.218443
             |
       _cons |   18.19239   .3186684    57.09   0.000     17.56586    18.81892
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  8.0054923
     sigma_e |  6.6977382
         rho |  .58824522   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* (3) psmatch2 for ATE and ATT */
. keep id fte treated t bk kfc roys

. qui reshape wide fte, i(id treated bk kfc roys) j(t)

. gen did_fte = fte1 - fte0

. psmatch2 treated bk kfc roys, outcome(fte0 fte1 did_fte) kernel kerneltype(normal) bw(0.05) common ate

Probit regression                               Number of obs     =        389
                                                LR chi2(3)        =       2.97
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.3956
Log likelihood = -189.22405                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0078

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          bk |   .1368372   .2190829     0.62   0.532    -.2925573    .5662318
         kfc |   .4092482   .2579891     1.59   0.113    -.0964012    .9148976
        roys |   .2448943   .2415267     1.01   0.311    -.2284893    .7182778
       _cons |   .6744898   .1889631     3.57   0.000     .3041288    1.044851
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variable     Sample |    Treated     Controls   Difference         S.E.   T-stat
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
            fte0  Unmatched | 17.0692675   20.1733333  -3.10406582   1.21654594    -2.55
                        ATT | 17.0692675   20.4710986  -3.40183108    1.4673544    -2.32
                        ATU | 20.1733333   17.6299058  -2.54342757            .        .
                        ATE |                          -3.23632912            .        .
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
            fte1  Unmatched | 17.5183121        17.65  -.131687898   1.11242821    -0.12
                        ATT | 17.5183121   17.7918742  -.273562085   1.05193873    -0.26
                        ATU |      17.65   18.0632041   .413204067            .        .
                        ATE |                          -.141152158            .        .
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
         did_fte  Unmatched | .449044586  -2.52333333   2.97237792    1.1318176     2.63
                        ATT | .449044586  -2.67922441     3.128269   1.35190664     2.31
                        ATU |-2.52333333   .433298308   2.95663164            .        .
                        ATE |                           3.09517696            .        .
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
Note: S.E. does not take into account that the propensity score is estimated.

           | psmatch2:
 psmatch2: |   Common
 Treatment |  support
assignment | On suppor |     Total
-----------+-----------+----------
 Untreated |        75 |        75 
   Treated |       314 |       314 
-----------+-----------+----------
     Total |       389 |       389 


. 
. /* (4) IPW Matching ATT=ATET and ATE */
. teffects ipw (did_fte) (treated bk kfc roys, probit), atet vce(robust) // osample(ipw1)  

Iteration 0:   EE criterion =  1.142e-28  
Iteration 1:   EE criterion =  3.433e-31  

Treatment-effects estimation                    Number of obs     =        389
Estimator      : inverse-probability weights
Outcome model  : weighted mean
Treatment model: probit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
     did_fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ATET         |
     treated |
 (NJ vs PA)  |   2.631046   1.220372     2.16   0.031     .2391604    5.022931
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
POmean       |
     treated |
         PA  |  -2.182001   1.130429    -1.93   0.054      -4.3976    .0335979
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. teffects ipw (did_fte) (treated bk kfc roys, probit), ate vce(robust) // osample(ipw2)  

Iteration 0:   EE criterion =  1.147e-28  
Iteration 1:   EE criterion =  1.002e-31  

Treatment-effects estimation                    Number of obs     =        389
Estimator      : inverse-probability weights
Outcome model  : weighted mean
Treatment model: probit
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
     did_fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ATE          |
     treated |
 (NJ vs PA)  |   2.712311   1.238966     2.19   0.029      .283982     5.14064
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
POmean       |
     treated |
         PA  |  -2.247811   1.146997    -1.96   0.050    -4.495884    .0002625
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To summarize, Kernel PSM DID and its regression analogue as well as PSM with `psmatch2` on differences yield an ATT of 3.13 FTEs. The weights from this program are more involved than the IPW weights.

The IPW on differences and the regression analogue you propose are similar to each other with an ATT of 2.63 FTEs, but smaller than the PSM based-estimates, though the differences are not significant.

---

**Code:**

```
cls
set more off
estimates clear
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/c/CardKrueger1994.dta, clear
/* Need to balance the panels so that all the methods use the same sample */
drop if missing(fte)
bys id (t): keep if _N==2

/* (1) -diff- to get ATT */
diff fte, treated(treated) period(t) id(id) cov(bk kfc roys) kernel ktype(gaussian) support bw(0.05) cluster(id) robust // report
assert _support==1

/* (2a) Regression Using Kernel Weights for ATE */
reg fte i.treated##i.t [aw=_weights], cluster(id) robust
xtset id t
xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [aw=_weights], fe cluster(id) robust

/* Create ATT and ATE Weights for regressions*/
/* You can install -xfill- by typing net from http://www.sealedenvelope.com/ and clicking on the name */
xfill _ps, i(id)
gen double w_att = cond(treated==1,1,_ps/(1-_ps))
gen double w_ate = cond(treated==1,1/_ps,1/(1-_ps))

/* (2b) Regression Using ATT and ATE IPW Weights */
reg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_att] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
reg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_ate] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_att], fe cluster(id) robust
xtreg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w_ate], fe cluster(id) robust

/* (3) psmatch2 for ATE and ATT */
keep id fte treated t bk kfc roys
qui reshape wide fte, i(id treated bk kfc roys) j(t)
gen did_fte = fte1 - fte0
psmatch2 treated bk kfc roys, outcome(fte0 fte1 did_fte) kernel kerneltype(normal) bw(0.05) common ate

/* (4) IPW Matching ATT=ATET and ATE */
teffects ipw (did_fte) (treated bk kfc roys, probit), atet vce(robust) // osample(ipw1)  
teffects ipw (did_fte) (treated bk kfc roys, probit), ate vce(robust) // osample(ipw2)
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy, your explanation is comprehensive and very useful. Anyway, I have some questions regarding your answers above:

1. do I need to use cluster(id) option when using -diff- command? what if not?

2. You kernel regression using command -reg- even the data you used is panel, can we use xtreg instead of reg?

3. Did you use regression from (1) to (4) simultaneously? 

Thank you.

Comment: @pututpurwandono (1) You don't have to cluster with `diff`, but I wanted to the standard errors to match `reg`, where I clustered. You could also cluster on other variables, like city or region, as long as there are enough of them.

Comment: (2) You could certainly use `xtreg`, but the estimates would be identical to `reg`.

Comment: (3) I am not sure what this means, but I think the answer is yes. I will add my code so that you can run the code yourself.

Comment: @pututpurwandono DiD this help?

Comment: Your solution seems helpful so far. I want to try your steps first. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand command at 2b:

Comment: I don't really understand what this command (in 2b) means:

xfill _ps, i(id) --> what is xfill means for? my Stata 14.1 cannot execute this.

reg fte i.treated##i.t [pw=w] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust

what does this part /*if_support==1*/ means? I tried to run this command and Stata does not work.

Comment: Xfill is a user-written command that extends the propensity score to the second period. You can find it via Google. The if condition is commented out, so it does not apply. It would restrict the regression to the observations where there there is overlap in the propensity score across groups between treated and untreated observations.

Comment: @pututpurwandono You can get `xfill` by typing "net from http://www.sealedenvelope.com/" and clicking on the name.

Comment: I think I know the function of xfill, it is just to copy the propensity scores in the baseline year to the follow-up year whose score is a "." (dot). Am I correct?

Comment: I believe that your psmatch2 is to obtain matched samples to be used in -teffects-, am I correct? But why you put the three outcomes in the same bracket in your psmatch2?

Comment: Yes on xfill. The three outcomes give you the difference for treated from post to pre, that same difference for untreated, and the difference in differences.

Comment: I rewrote the answer extensively to hopefully make more sense. Also, psmatch2 and ipw are distinct commands: the latter is not an input for the former.

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy, you are so helpful. Anyway, the data from Card seems very simple as an example while my data is more complicated. Let me explain to you. My data set is 2-year panel (2010 and 2015). The outcome is continuous variable (ln)Y0 and (ln)Y1 for year 2010 and 2015 and the treatment is binary. I also have covariates for two years let say A0 & A1 for covariate A of 2010 and 2015 respectively, B0 & B1, C0 & C1 and D0 & D1. I will try to write the command by using step 2a to step 4. Please check whether my command below correct or not:

Comment: I defined did_lny = lny1 - lny0; did_a = a1-a0; did_b = b1-b0; did_c = c1 - c0 and did_d = d1 - d0.
A, B, C and D are covariates in long form

/* (2a) Regression Using Kernel Weights for ATE */
reg did_lny i.treated##i.t did_a did_b did_c did_d [aw=_weights], cluster(id) robust
xtset id t
xtreg lny i.treated##i.t A B C D [aw=_weights], fe cluster(id) robust

Comment: /* Create ATT and ATE Weights for regressions*/
/* You can install -xfill- by typing net from http://www.sealedenvelope.com/ and clicking on the name */
xfill _ps, i(id)
gen double w_att = cond(treated==1,1,_ps/(1-_ps))
gen double w_ate = cond(treated==1,1/_ps,1/(1-_ps))

Comment: /* (2b) Regression Using ATT and ATE IPW Weights */
reg did_lny i.treated##i.t did_a did_b did_c did_d [pw=w_att] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
reg did_lny i.treated##i.t did_a did_b did_c did_d [pw=w_ate] /*if _support==1*/, cluster(id) robust
xtreg lny i.treated##i.t A B C D [pw=w_att], fe cluster(id) robust
xtreg lny i.treated##i.t A B C D [pw=w_ate], fe cluster(id) robust

Comment: /* (3) psmatch2 for ATE and ATT */
keep id lny treated t A B C D
qui reshape wide lny, i(id A B C D) j(t)
gen did_lny = lny1 - lny0
psmatch2 treated a0 b0 c0 d0, outcome(did_lny) kernel kerneltype(normal) bw(0.05) common ate

/* (4) IPW Matching ATT=ATET and ATE */
teffects ipw (did_lny) (treated a0 b0 c0 d0, probit), atet vce(robust) // osample(ipw1)  
teffects ipw (did_lny) (treated a0 b0 c0 d0, probit), ate vce(robust) // osample(ipw2)

Comment: You should ask another question rather than doing this in the comments.

Comment: You wrote "Also, as an aside, you can never test the parallel paths or trends/growth assumptions, even if you had more data." Do you mean this in the general sense or that this is untestable in this setting? I mean, I must be able to plot the pre-trends using weighted data and confirm the parallel trend assumption visually, or test that groups have the same time-trends using a regression on weighted data? I am aware that these tests never can prove that trends are the same, only that we cannot reject the null

Comment: When parallel trends hold in the pre period, that does not mean that they would have held in the post without treatment, which is what you need. I am more likely to believe that if they do hold in the pre period, but it is an untestable assumption.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Can you please give references to studies that are using PSM DID and IPW DID?