# How do I properly run a propensity correction for a fixed-effects model in Stata?

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model, propensity-scores, heckman

I have a fixed effects regression with a highly unbalanced panel. I am recording the outcome for each day a person participates over the course of a fifteen year time frame. Individuals can enter or leave the panel at any time during this period. I am interested in if Group A changes more over time compared to Group Not A on the outcome measure (i.e. they have significantly different slopes when interacted with time). Complicating this is that those in Group A tend to spend more time in the panel. Given this, it seems that selection effects could bias the results so I calculated inverse probability weights for each person-day to still be in the panel using a survival model. However, Stata's xtreg only lets me use time-invariant weights: `weight must be constant within id`

My questions:

1. Does this approach make sense?
2. Is there a work around to let me run a fixed effect regression using weights for each observation individually?

Note: I tried to run the model in both R and Python but could not get even a non-weighted fixed effects model to run given the size of the data.

Comment: There a DID question here with [an approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365425/7071) that might work for you.