# How to use Kernel weighted PSM and IPW in Triple Difference estimator (ika Difference in Difference-in-Differences)

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, matching

I have learned a lot from @dimitriy answer in this post: [Propensity Scores Weighted DID](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228367/propensity-scores-weighted-did)

I am currently utilizing the triple difference estimator for estimating treatment effects (please see the paper about this estimator at https://academic.oup.com/ectj/article/25/3/531/6545797). I am interested in applying kernel-weighted propensity score matching (PSM) and inverse probability weighting (IPW) methods to estimate the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT).

More specifically, how to obtain the kernel weight and the propensity score in a DDD triple difference estimation? should the kernel weight or the inverted weight be applied only to the control group, or also to the 2nd treated group?

Thank you in advance.